# What’s the meaning of ‘stand hacking‘?

Tags: meaning-in-context, syntactic-analysis, intransitive-verbs, participial-phrases, predicative-complements

I'm trying to understand this sentence:

> For hours I **stood hacking** at the icy ground.

Which is in this excerpt of [Viktor Frankl’s 1947 book, *Man's Search for Meaning*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man%27s_Search_for_Meaning):

> Another time we were at work in a trench. The dawn was grey around us; grey was the sky above; grey the snow in the pale light of dawn; grey the rags in which my fellow prisoners were clad, and grey their faces. I was again conversing silently with my wife, or perhaps I was struggling to find the reason for my sufferings, my slow dying. In a last violent protest against the hopelessness of imminent death, I sensed my spirit piercing through the enveloping gloom. I felt it transcend that hopeless, meaningless world, and from somewhere I heard a victorious “Yes” in answer to my question of the existence of an ultimate purpose. At that moment a light was lit in a distant farmhouse, which stood on the horizon as
> if painted there, in the midst of the miserable grey of a dawning morning in Bavaria. “Et lux in tenebris lucet”—and the light shineth in the darkness. **For hours I stood hacking at the icy ground.** The guard passed by, insulting me, and once again I communed with my beloved. More and more I felt that she was present, that she was with me; I had the feeling that I was able to touch her, able to stretch out my hand and grasp hers. The feeling was very strong: she was there. Then, at that very moment, a bird flew down silently and perched just in front of me, on the heap of soil which I had dug up from the ditch, and looked steadily at me.

Does that meaning standing still with a frozen body?

Comment: There's a comma missing after "stood".

Comment: @HotLicks I sit here laughing at the notion of a comma gone missing there.

Comment: "Stood hacking" is **not a single constituent**, no more so than "came running" and "sat laughing" are single constituents. Instead, these three examples are all intransitive verbs in the past tense combined with a **separate *gerund–participial clause*  following** them, as explained in the duplicate I've marked this as.

Comment: thank you very much, it makes sense to me now!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not "stand hacking" (hacking of a stand?).

No:  I stood (I was on two legs, not walking).  While I stood, I hacked (struck repeatedly, using some tool) at the ground.  This is how I (and the other prisoners) were making a trench.

Comment: You might want to add: with a pickax.

Comment: @Lambie or a pick-axe, or pickaxe.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Merriam Webster: https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/pickax **pickax**. Depends on the side of the pond.

Comment: @Lambie - well, Victor Frankl was Austrian, based in Vienna, so maybe he'd use _eine Spitzhacke_?

Comment: @MichaelHarvey It's hardly a strictly pondian distinction. Even in North America we commonly write [pickaxe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pickaxe), just as we often write *hand axe, throwing axe, battle-axe, pole-axe,* and *stone-axe*. Although **some** North American writers lose the *e* in the singular, **many others** retain it in all instances and compounds (whether open like *hand axe*, hyphenated like *hand-axe*, or spaceless like *handaxe*). The [U.S.A.’s *National **Axe** Throwing Federation*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/National_Axe_Throwing_Federation) uses the canonical spelling.

Comment: thank you very much, it makes sense to me now!